# $event.stopPropagation() not working inside dropdown toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dom-events

I'm trying to keep dropdown menu opened when I click on the second selector by using

> $event.stopPropagation()

but it's not working as expected.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header"><b>Example</b></li>
    <li><a>Example 1</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="$event.stopPropagation()">Example 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Example 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Example 4</a></li>
    <li><a >Example 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please suggest is there any other way to handle this using CSS -keeping ''open' class active on click..

Comment: What is `$event` a reference to?

Comment: $event reference to the global event object

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it helps,thanks

```js
    $('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e){
      console.log('List has been clicked')
    })
    $(".link").click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
     });
```

```css
.link
{
color:red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header"><b>Example</b></li>
    <li><a>Example 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Example 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Example 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Example 4</a></li>
    <li><a >Example 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I wanted to have solution directly using HTML or CSS.Any idea of unhiding the class using css by having an id?

Comment: You can use display block inline of html tag so that it cannot be overridden